# LocalProcessingException occured on report.Render line

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc

In following code it gives me an error here, i dont have an idea what am i missing here. Error: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll Additional information: An error occurred during local report processing. Here is my code:

```
  public void Export(LocalReport report)
{
    string deviceInfo =
      @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;
    m_streams = new List<Stream>();
    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
       out warnings);
    foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
        stream.Position = 0;
}
```

Comment: add try catch here and catch 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException'
see what is the error message

Comment: While not the cause of the exception, that code won't work - the `report.Render` method returns a `Byte[]` which can be converted into a stream.